# How to use WebSphere 8.5.5 without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, server, websphere

how can I use WebSphere 8.5.5 without using Eclipse's Plugin (IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools plugin).

In modern Eclipse it isn't working anymore because (Eclipse says) *some Websphere Application Server specific functions are only supported on JRE 6.0, 7.0, or 8.0.*

**I would like to create new Servers, start, stop, start in debug, publish EAR files, check Server status.**

I have many Profiles I previously use with Eclipse Server's View, which due to Plugin compatibility I can't manage anymore, and I would like to reuse them in some way.

Many thanks

Comment: Java 11 or higher is required to _run_ Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17), but you can still code and use Java 8 and lower.

Comment: You use the 'Java > Installed JREs' in the Preferences to tell Eclipse about the Java you want to use to run your program, so you can still use Java 6/7/8 to run Websphere in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Websphere Java 1.7 in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs but every time I try to interact with the servers I get  `An internal error occurred during: "Starting Server G2". org/omg/CORBA/UserException`

Comment: Are you sure that this is not because you missed the last update of the [_IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85x-developer-tools#group-metrics-tab) plugin in late August, early September?

Comment: @howlger I tried with version `20.0.0.9.v20200826` of the developer tools and the error still occurs, I switched back to eclipse 2020-06.

Answer (score 1):

See the "Using command-line Tools" topic in the IBM KnowledgeCenter https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_command.html

To create a new server profile w/o Eclipse, use the WebSphere Customization Toolbox (wct) in <WAS_HOME>/bin.  You can also use the Profile Management Tool, pmt, but that has been deprecated

To start (normal or debug) a server, use startServer script in <PROFILE_HOME>/bin

To stop a server, use stopServer script in <PROFILE_HOME>/bin

To publish an EAR (or WAR) file, you can either use the web-based admin console or the wsadmin command line.  There are a number of scripts available to help with this task in <WAS_HOME>/scriptLibraries/application/V70, their various functions are described in the KnowledgeCenter topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_7libapp.html

To check server status, use serverStatus script in <PROFILE_HOME>/bin